# Wildcard in Word 2013 to match zero or more whitespaces

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

What is the analog of regular expression's `*` modifier in Word 2013 wildcards?

In Word 2013 Find tool with wildcards enabled, apparently 0 is not a valid number as the number of matches. For example, if you type in the search box

> fe{1,2}d

it will match `fed` and `feed`. However,

> fe{0,2}d

will just produce an error message. What is the correct expression to match `fd`, `fed`, `feed`, `feeed`, etc.?

My motivation is to match a specific text when it is in a paragraph alone (i.e., surrounded by paragraph marks `^13`) but with a possible whitespaces after it:

> ^13hello world {0,}^13

which just produces an error message. I did not find any solution without enabling wildcards, but even with wildcards enabled I can't get it working.

Similarly,

> ^13hello world @^13

matches one or more spaces, but I need zero or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Word has ever had an equivalent for the zero-or-more operator, so while I haven't checked in Word 2013, I wouldn't expect to see it there either. (This page is old, but as far as I know it's still pretty authoritative on wildcard searching in Word: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm)

**In general**, I would suggest doing two searches, one without the character and one using the 1-or-more operator.

ETA: Removed bad wildcard search.

Comment: It doesn't exist. You can just do two finds, one with no instance of the character and one with 1 or more.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish typing my comment -- I mean, not exactly what is needed: it will also match the text before a space even if not alone on the paragraph, such as `^13Hellow world bla bla bla`, while the question was how to match only  `^13Hellow world^13` and `^13Hellow world   ^13`.

Comment: Yes, looks like it doesn't exist (thanks Microsoft!). I suggest you make it an answer so that I can accept it. I am reluctant to accept the answer above because it suggests an incorrect pattern.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a general case. I do think it's worth considering ways to rewrite a wildcard search, so I'm leaving the specific answer as well (but noted as such. You are correct that that is not always an acceptable workaround for zero-or-more).

Comment: "But, if you're just trying to ensure that the text is on a line of its own, it should work." No, it does not ensure that the text is on a line of its own, a counterexample is `^13Hello world bla bla bla`.

Comment: Blurgh, sorry, did not see the rest of your comment. You're completely right, I'll strike that part through.

Comment: I don't use this Find feature often, but **in this specific case** it might be worth seeing if "^phello world^p" with wildcards turned off and ignore whitespace turned on works. It seems to in a quick test (if you don't mind lumping other whitespace in with standard spaces, which you very well might).